# Sorted data structure

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, sortedlist, sorteddictionary

I am looking for a sorted keyed data structure in .Net 4.0 supporting the following functionality:

1. Create the structure in `O(n log n)` time
2. Get the item by key in `O(log n)` time
3. Find the smallest item in the collection greater or equal to a given argument in `O(log n)` time (we will key it using `double` most probably)
4. Find the biggest item smaller than a given argument in `O(log n)`
5. For a given item in the collection, get the next and previous item
6. Keys need to be unique in the collection

I took a quick look at the `SortedDictionary` and `SortedList`, but they don't seem to provide (3) and (4) from the list above. `SortedDictionary` doesn't seem to support (5),
and I am not sure if `SortedList` supports (6).

We are limited to `.Net4` unfortunately.

Comment: This sounds as you need to build such a data structure yourself.

Comment: I have no idea if they have such a structure, but have you looked at [C5 Collections](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/)? Lots of goodness in there, they've an NuGet package too `PM> Install-Package C5`

Comment: Is the collection just key of Double?  Find biggest item smaller you mean searching on the key?

Comment: @Blam, yes, that is correct. `double` would be the key, but we still have some values associated with it.

Comment: I get this is probably not news to you but the biggest item smaller and smallest item greater is the hard part.  Cannot do that with hashbuckets.  For O(log n) I think that will need to be like an index seek.  Did you look an in memory database like a Redis.io?

Comment: @Blam, this is easily implementable as a tree data structure. I really wanted to avoid having to implement and test one myself.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to write your own collection.  Conceptually what you want appears to be a tree based structure, which is how `SortedDictionary` is implemented.  The underlying structure has the potential for all of these tasks, the .NET implementation simply doesn't expose them all, nor does it provide access to enough of the underlying tools to accomplish those goals, forcing you to start from scratch.

Fortunately, building such tree based structures is a common task for introductory programmers, so as a result you'll find plenty of open source 3rd party implementations to look through, either that will accomplish your goals, or as a starting place.  You could also consider [grabbing the source of SortedDictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sorteddictionary.cs#1a01ea5555bded49) and re-compiling your own version, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sorted dictionary for you. I hope it meets your needs.

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TItem> : IDictionary<TKey, TItem>
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
    where TItem : IEquatable<TItem>
{
    private readonly List<TKey> keys;
    private readonly List<TItem> items;
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<TKey> roKeys;
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<TItem> roItems;

    public MyDictionary()
    {
        keys = new List<TKey>();
        items = new List<TItem>();
        roKeys = new ReadOnlyCollection<TKey>(keys);
        roItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<TItem>(items);
    }

    public MyDictionary(int capacity)
    {
        keys = new List<TKey>(capacity);
        items = new List<TItem>(capacity);
        roKeys = new ReadOnlyCollection<TKey>(keys);
        roItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<TItem>(items);
    }

    public MyDictionary(TKey[] keys, TItem[] items)
    {
        if (keys == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("keys");
        if (items == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
        if (keys.Length != items.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException("Arrays lengths must be equal.");

        TKey[] keysCopy = new TKey[keys.Length];
        keys.CopyTo(keysCopy, 0);
        TItem[] itemsCopy = new TItem[items.Length];
        items.CopyTo(itemsCopy, 0);

        Array.Sort(keysCopy, itemsCopy);

        this.keys = new List<TKey>(keysCopy);
        this.items = new List<TItem>(itemsCopy);
        roKeys = new ReadOnlyCollection<TKey>(keys);
        roItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<TItem>(items);
    }

    public int BinarySearch(TKey key)
    {
        return keys.BinarySearch(key);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return BinarySearch(key) >= 0;
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TItem item)
    {
        int index = BinarySearch(key);
        if (index >= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The key {0} already exists.", key), "key");
        index = ~index;
        keys.Insert(index, key);
        items.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem> item)
    {
        Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        int index = BinarySearch(key);
        if (index < 0)
            return false;
        keys.RemoveAt(index);
        items.RemoveAt(index);
        return true;
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem> item)
    {
        int index = BinarySearch(item.Key);
        if (index < 0)
            return false;
        index = ~index;
        keys.RemoveAt(index);
        items.RemoveAt(index);
        return true;
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem> item)
    {
        int index = BinarySearch(item.Key);
        if (index < 0)
            return false;
        index = ~index;
        return items[index].Equals(item.Value);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TItem value)
    {
        int index = BinarySearch(key);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            value = default(TItem);
            return false;
        }
        value = items[index];
        return true;
    }

    public TItem this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            int index = BinarySearch(key);
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The key {0} not found.", key), "key");
            return items[index];
        }
        set
        {
            int index = BinarySearch(key);
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The key {0} not found.", key), "key");
            items[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return roKeys; }
    }

    public ICollection<TItem> Values
    {
        get { return roItems; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return keys.Select((t, i) => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem>(t, items[i])).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        keys.Clear();
        items.Clear();
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Array.Copy(keys.Select((t, i) => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem>(t, items[i])).ToArray(), 0, array, arrayIndex, Count);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return keys.Count; } 
    }

    public int Capacity
    {
        get { return keys.Capacity; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
            keys.Capacity = value;
            items.Capacity = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public int GetSmallerOrEqualIndex(TKey key)
    {
        int index = BinarySearch(key);
        if (index >= 0)
            return index;
        index = ~index;
        return index - 1;
    }

    public int GetGreaterOrEqualIndex(TKey key)
    {
        int index = BinarySearch(key);
        if (index >= 0)
            return index;
        index = ~index;
        return index;
    }

    public KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem> GetItem(int index)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TItem>(keys[index], items[index]);
    }
}
```

The requirements:

1. NOT Satisfied (I'm working on it). At the moment, initializing via `MyDictionary(TKey[] keys, TItem[] items)` constructor is on average an O(n log n) operation, in the worst case it is an O(n ^ 2) operation. Adding an individual item is an O(n) operation.
2. Satisfied.
3. Satisfied (`GetGreaterOrEqualIndex` method).
4. Satisfied (`GetSmallerOrEqualIndex` method).
5. Not satisfied directly, but satisfied for the item's index, if I understood "given item" correctly.
6. Satisfied.

Comment: #1 is not satisfied.  Adding N items to this data structure is an O(n^2) operation.

Comment: Why? Adding 1 item is an O(log N) operation. Adding N items - O(N log N). I missed something?

Comment: Adding 1 item to a list is an O(n) operation, not an O(log(n)) operation.  Finding the index of where to add it is O(log(n)), but actually adding it once you have the index is O(n).

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx): If `Count` is less than `Capacity`, this method is an O(1) operation. But you are right, I should add this moment to the answer.

Comment: That is only true when adding to the end.  You are not adding to the end of the list.  You are adding to the middle of the list, which is an O(n) operation, even when a new buffer allocation *isn't* needed.

Comment: My bad. You are right. I'll try to modify the code in order to satisfy #1. Thank you.

Comment: It's an inherently unavoidable situation.  You would need to use a tree based structure to meet all of the requirements, basically doing a complete re-write of the whole thing.